# Enumeration yielded no results with imported function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I try to test my imported function like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCustomerById()
{
    using (var ctx = new AWLT.AWLT())
    {
        var customer = ctx.GetCustomerById(1);
        // Assert.AreNotEqual(0, customer.Count());
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0,
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext
            .ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged).Count());
    }
}
```

---

When I debug the test and try to quick watch `customer` I get :

> Enumeration yielded no results

although when I run the procedure it returns a one customer !!

Comment: Did you check the query generated by EF?

Comment: You should call .ToList() to force enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

You should call .ToList() to force enumerator.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCustomerById()
{
    using (var ctx = new AWLT.AWLT())
    {
        var customer = ctx.GetCustomerById(1).ToList();
        // Assert.AreNotEqual(0, customer.Count());
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0,
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext
            .ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged).Count());
    }
}
```